# How to construct restful routing in Spree + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, spree

How to have resourceful routing in Spree in Rails.

I am adding my routes using get/post request. (as mentioned below)

```
devise_scope :spree_user do
    get '/users/profile', to: "devise/sessions#new", as: 'user_signin'
    post '/is_email_registered', to: 'spree/user_registrations#is_email_registered'
    post '/update_password',  to: 'spree/user_registrations#update_password'
    delete '/signout', :to => 'spree/user_sessions#destroy'
  end


  get "/product_list",  to: 'spree/products#snack_list'
  get "/product_view",  to: 'spree/products#snack_show'
```

Instead of this kind of named routing, I would like to use resourceful routing with Spree + Rails. 
tried with resources :spree_users or resources :products, but those don't work.

How to get this kind of resourceful routing in Spree !

Answer (score 0):

Within one of my projects, the routing is set up as so:

```
Site::Application.routes.draw do
  # some code to set the root and what not

  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'

  Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
    # Your Usual Routes Here
  end
end
```

Because of this, I would rewrite your routes as:

```
mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'

Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
  resources :spree_user do
    get '/users/profile', to: "devise/sessions#new", as: 'user_signin'
    post '/is_email_registered', to: 'spree/user_registrations#is_email_registered'
    post '/update_password',  to: 'spree/user_registrations#update_password'
    delete '/signout', :to => 'spree/user_sessions#destroy'
  end

  get "/product" => 'spree/products#snack_list'
  match "/product/:view" => 'spree/products#snack_show'
end
```

Although, within resources, I haven't updated it or rewrote it. I think its specific to your project and you should check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for more information on routing.

I've also removed devise in my answer... I'm probably being more detrimental than helpful...

Comment and let me know if I'm helping lol.